# Final Cut Pro X - Generate video from files in folder

Tags: plugins, video-processing, video-editing, finalcut

I am not sure if this is possible, or even possible with a plugin.
Or even if it is possible to develop a plugin to perform something like this.

So currently I am creating compilation videos in which the template I have is an intro, a number of clips with short 1sec video clip between each of these clips and the outro.

I want to be able to simply create a new folder for each compilation on my computer, add the clips I want and then trigger final cut pro x to generate the video.

I know this is very simplified but I just want to understand if this is at all possible, or something similar as it would really help me cut down the time needed to drag and drop clips, remove sections if the amount of clips is less/more etc.

Alternatively if there is other software outside of final cut pro x I would love to hear about it,

Thank you

Comment: If you haven't accomplished this yet, it's easy to do using Ruby and ffmpeg.  In fact you can automate this even further depending on your setup.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

FCP X cannot be used for that. The best way to get what you want is to use [The Foundry NUKE](https://www.foundry.com/products/nuke). This node-based compositing app works on Windows, macOS and Linux, and allows you to process and manage a video, photo and 3D models via Python scripting.

The code for creating a new directory in macOS using NUKE's `Script Editor` looks like this:

```python
import nuke
import os

def createWriteDir():
    file = nuke.filename(nuke.thisNode())
    dir = os.path.dirname(file)
    osdir = nuke.callbacks.filenameFilter(dir)
    try:
        os.makedirs(osdir)
        return
    except:
        return

nuke.addBeforeRender(createWriteDir)
```